# How do I handle route exception not defined?

Tags: laravel, exception, routes

I created dynamic sidebar menu and when I try to insert new menu I am getting error message `Route [nameroute] is not defined`. How do I handle this error with try catch ?

This is my controller file.

```
DB::beginTransaction();
try
{
   $insert = AppMenu::insertGetId([
            'description' => $request->description,
            'menu_url' => $request->menu_url ? $request->menu_url:null,
            'menu_alias' => $request->menu_alias ? $request->menu_alias:null,
            'ismenu' => $request->ismenu,
            'parent' => $request->parent ? $request->parent:null,
            'menu_icon' => $request->menu_icon,
            'menu_order' => $request->menu_order
   ]);

   DB::table('appmenu_role')->insert([
                'appmenu_id' => $insert,
                'role_id'    => $role
                ]);


        }
        catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e)
        {
            return Redirect::back()->with('infoMessage', "Route not defined. ");
        }

        DB::commit();
        Session::flash('successMessage', 'Menu Created');
        return Redirect('menu');
```

Comment: Are you using Laravel framework?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Exception` class to catch any kind of exception.

```
catch (\Exception $e)
{
        return Redirect::back()->with('infoMessage', "Route not defined.");
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that this controller is executed ?